# Widgets with non-duplicate values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to build a widget from a list that has non-duplicate values based on the below scenario. Could someone please help me with getting the right way?

```
fileInfoList = list(filter(lambda f: f.name.endswith("") , dbutils.fs.ls(srcPath)))
for fileNames in fileInfoList:
  print(fileNames.name)
```

This prints:
Employee
EmployeeHistory
Contractor
ContractorHistory

What I wanted is only the values without History.
Tried this but returns error:

```
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("FileName", "Employee", [str(fileNames.name) for fileNames in fileInfoList])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply filter your list before feeding into the dropdown function?

```
>> fileList = ['Employee', 'Contractor', 'EmployeeHistory', 'ContractorHistory']
>> print(fileList)
   ['Employee', 'Contractor', 'EmployeeHistory', 'ContractorHistory']

>> filteredFileList = [item for item in fileList if 'History' not in item]
>> print(filteredFileList)
   ['Employee', 'Contractor']
```